# If conditional giving true although it's supposed to be false

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I'm  having problem with the conditional always returning true. I'm not sure if it's the value it's seeing as truthy in general but it's messing with me.

```
Problem: Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any char.

Examples input/output:

XO("ooxx") => true
XO("xooxx") => false
XO("ooxXm") => true
XO("zpzpzpp") => true // when no 'x' and 'o' is present should return true
XO("zzoo") => false
```

```
function XO(str) {
  let on = 0
  let xn = 0 

  let result = ""
  for (let i = 0; i <=str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] = "x" || "X"){
      xn++
    } if (str[i] = "o" || "O") {

      on++
    };

    if (xn == on || xn && on == 0){
      result = true
    }else  if  (xn !== on) {
      result = false

    }

    return  result
  } 

}
```

Seems the conditional is always returning true. Not sure if it's because the types are true (which is why I kept it strict).

Comment: problem 1 ... `=` is **assignment** ... so `str[i] = "x"` ASSIGNS the value `"x"` to `str[i]` - and `"x"` is "truthy"... if you were to fix that by using `==` instead, then problem 2 .. `str[i] == "x" || "X"` is not how you check if `str[1]` is equal to `"x"` or `"X"` ... `str[i] == "x" || str[i] == "X"` is ... or `str[i].toLwoerCase() == "x"` of course would work

Comment: I've just changed it and I still have the same problems here is the new code
```
 function XO(str) {
  let on = 0
let xn = 0 

let result = ""
for (let i = 0; i <=str.length; i++) {
 if (str[i].toLowerCase() == "x"){ 
xn++


} if (str[i].toLowerCase() == "o") {

on++
};

  if (xn == on || xn && on == 0){
result = true
}else  if  (xn !== on) {
result = false

}

return  result
} 

}

```

Comment: You probably meant to put `return result` outside the loop. Consider using correct indentation to spot those types of issues easier.

Comment: `i <= str.length` is a very common off-by-one error.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 mistakes in your `XO` function.

1. You have used assignment operator : `=` instead of equality
   comparison operator : `==`.
2. You are checking condition `str[i] == "x" || "X"`. The correct way to write this is : `str[i] == "x" || str[i] == "X"`.
3. You are checking `xn==on` inside the for loop. You should check that once your for loop is over.

Here is the correct code -

```
function XO(str) {
    let on = 0
    let xn = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == "x" || str[i] == "X") {
            xn++
            continue;
        } 
        if (str[i] == "o" || str[i] == "O") {
            on++
            continue;
        };
    }
    return xn==on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use `toLowerCase()` and at the end return if `on===xn`

```js
function XO(str) {
  let on = 0;
  let xn = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "x") {
      xn++;
    }
    if (str[i].toLowerCase() === "o") {
      on++;
    };
  }
  return xn === on
}


console.log(XO("ooxx"))
console.log(XO("xooxx"))
console.log(XO("ooxXm"))
console.log(XO("zpzpzpp"))
console.log(XO("zzoo"))
```